# Raphael: How to center circle inside div

Tags: javascript, raphael

I want to create cricle in center of div. Here is my http://jsfiddle.net/uuAjV/3/
If I set amount to 75, it will display correct position of circle, but if I change variable **amount** to less then 75, then position of circle starts in weird places.
Here is my code

```
var amount = 75;
var archtype = Raphael("canvas", 500, 500);
archtype.customAttributes.arc = function (xloc, yloc, value, total, R) {
    var alpha = 360 / total * value, 
        a = (90 - alpha) * Math.PI / 180,
        x = xloc + R * Math.cos(a),
        y = yloc - R * Math.sin(a),
        path;
    if (total == value) {
        path = [
            ["M", xloc, yloc - R],
            ["A", R, R, 0, 1, 1, xloc - 0.01, yloc - R]
        ];
    } else {
        path = [
            ["M", xloc, yloc - R],
            ["A", R, R, 0, +(alpha > 180), 1, x, y]
        ];
    }
    return {
        path: path
    };
};


var my_arc = archtype.path().attr({
    "stroke": "#f00",
    "stroke-width": 2,
    arc: [100, 100, amount, 100, 100]
}).rotate(180);
```

I have tried change:

```
["M", xloc, yloc - R],
```

to:

```
["M", 100, 200],
```

So it would start from bottom od div, but it didn't work

Any help how to fix it? I want to have circle always in middle of div. For example: this is how is should look if amount is set to 25.
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect what you're wanting to achieve can be obtained by changing the rotate to rotate(180, 100, 100) so that you're rotating about the centre rather than some other point. I.e.

```
var my_arc = archtype.path().attr({
    "stroke": "#f00",
    "stroke-width": 2,
    arc: [100, 100, amount, 100, 100]
}).rotate(180, 100, 100);
```

Comment: Wow, it works perfect. Thanks a lot! I didn't know rotate function accepts more then 1 parameter. Thanks again!